# Can't Load Rails Server Even Could not find pg-0.17.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubygems, nokogiri

pretty new to all this and ran into a real ditch.  I had ruby 2.0.0p353 running with rails 4.1+, everything was setup with homebrew, xcode, git,heroku etc.... I'm on OSX 10.9.4

then came time to try out S3 and install the aws-sdk gem.  I was unable to install the nokogiri gem after scouring stackoverflow for days to no avail.  I then came across this article online that suggested to update rails and ruby versions.  In my attempt to upgrade my ruby version to the latest, I followed the instructions given [here](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrading-ruby-osx/)  as follows:

in terminal and in my app folder:

1. /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
2. export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
3. source  ~/.bash_profile
4. gem update --system
   ..I subsequently tried bundle update / installs as well... and receive this error shown on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Q64j0LwD

Now, things are completely messed up as I am unable to even run a rails server. Getting this error Could not find pg-0.17.1 in any of the sources

I currently have Ruby 2.1.2p95 installed.  I don't know what else is installed during this trial and error probably several versions of many things unfortunately.  Any advice would be great.

: Could not find pg-0.17.1 in any of the sources

Comment: It can't find the postgres headers to build `pg`. Is PostgreSQL installed? If so, how was it installed?

Comment: Hi Colinm, I believe I just added the gem 'pg' under group: production do in the gemfile.

Comment: have you done `bundle install` after adding `pg` to your gemfile?

Comment: Hi @SachinSingh yes, i had gem 'pg' under group :production in gemfile

Comment: if you're running a rails server locally, with "rails s", then you are using the development environment by default. If the gem is marked as being for production only, then you have no pg gem for dev usage - and so a dev server will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`postgresapp`](http://postgresapp.com/) and use [`documentation`](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/) for install and configure `postgresql` server.

> The easiest way to get started with PostgreSQL on the Mac

Answer (score 0):

You're clearly new to rails coding. I made a lot of mistakes when I started. I still make a lot of mistakes, but they're more complex mistakes now, mostly ;)

I'd start by using "[RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en)". Excellent way to get all the pieces... except Postgres. As suggested by someone with a name consisting of a lot of non-ASCII characters, [PostgresApp](http://postgresapp.com/) is incredibly useful to get a more up to date Postgres without messing with compiling stuff outside the project.

You probably should use "[rvm](https://rvm.io/)" or "[rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)" to manage your rubies. I've tried both, and I favour rvm. rbenv is recommended, but I spent an awkward half day trying to disentangle the consequence of typing "bundle exec rails new app", before I decided to go back to rvm. rvm works more naturally for me, at the expense of creating gemsets for each project. Which, personally, I like. I want to isolate each thing I add to an OS, so I can work on multiple projects with less contamination, and without having to create a VM for each project.

Contamination is, I think the problem with Nokogiri. Everyone tells you to go install brew or Macports or build it all for yourself from scratch. When you do, you get lots of stuff installed. And that stuff affects the compilation process. I'm about 80% certain that I can't compile Nokogiri with system libraries because other projects have dropped include files that rename iconv_open to libiconv_open - which isn't in the native library. I have Nokogiri compiling now, but only as a result of using GNU iconv, and using the arcane "bundle config" to set up a build time dependency for nokogiri alone to use the /opt/local/include version of iconv. That was time consuming.

So, some advice that I haven't taken for myself yet. Clean out the brew/ports stuff. I suspect that you can run anything you *need* to, in locally installed project directories, rather than interfering with the OS. Unless you really need something that doesn't ship with a Mac, like an up to date ruby (solved by rbenv/rvm)

Look into [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/). Low cost way to get started with publishing your small apps.

Make sure you have [GitHub](https://github.com/) and [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) accounts. Personally I contribute to projects on GitHub, but my private stuff is on BitBucket - pricing models.

Git looks mad. But git is wonderful. Learn to branch. Lots. Learn to merge. Learn to tag, and learn how to push and pull from an upstream repo. These words may mean nothing to you now, but they will save your sanity. You'll use git to push your projects to Heroku. Just freaking amazing. Learn how to have a staging branch and a live branch, and push each to a different Heroku instance, so you can be testing user acceptance on a public facing server, without contaminating dev or live versions. Git/Heroku. Joyful.

Watch out for several things that bit me... Ruby gets lots of patches. They are meaningful. I spent days trying to work out why a piece of ruby code failed, only to discover it worked in a different patch level. Watch for the updates and apply them - except for 'bundle update'. Don't do 'bundle update' until you are old and wise.

Gem versions - that also bit me. Got a project that worked. Then it didn't, with no code changes at all... except that I'd updated my gems. A later version of a gem upset the code. So...

Bundler is your other friend. Lock down the versions of gems that you need for a project. Don't use "bundle update" unless you are prepared for strange things to happen. Make nice Gemfiles.

You probably need to get to grips with TDD and preferably BDD.

So next thing you need is to get the [Qt](http://qt-project.org/downloads) library installed, and use "gem 'capybara-webkit'" and Cucumber with Rspec-Rails to help you write tests that the browser will execute. Butt saver central, if you start changing gem versions. At least you *know* when the tests stopped working, and can use git to revert to a known working chunk. More importantly, it saves, eventually, a lot of tedious checking around when something unexpectedly stops working.

Also... make sure that your development group of gems (in Gemfile) includes "better_errors" and "binding_of_caller". A REPL in the browser pane when your code fails, is wonderful.

If you want to just throw some stuff together, e.g. office admin projects that you don't want to spend a load of time refining the UI on, but just build something that *works*. Try '[hobo](http://hobocentral.net/)'. I find it very useful for rapidly building something. Faster to code it than to spec it or draw it. Seriously. And it is all over-rideable, though I've never turned any Hobo code into something for high scaled usage...

Welcome to the amazing world of developing in Rails, on a Mac. It's a rapidly evolving hoot. Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for this in depth response JezC I have noted all the references and will look into them.  Do you have any advice for me on how to uninstall the original pg/rails/gems that seem lost in my mac so I can start new?  they are definitely installed somewhere lol.

Comment: Haven't, as I suggested, done it myself. I'm about to sacrifice a Mac Mini to this cause, in the next few weeks. I'd look at shell login profile changes (/etc/profile.d/*, and ~/.bash_rc, ~/.profile, etc) for some residues. Then I'd *CAREFULLY* remove /opt/local and possibly /usr/local. Why carefully? Because you may have useful stuff in there. The issue you probably need to sort is the minimum changes required to have nokogiri compile. Unless you have other Mac OS X projects that rely on GNU libs.

Comment: Thanks, I'm presenting my mac to a group of ruby enthusiasts wednesday evening to see what they say in person.  I'll def come back with an update.  Thanks again.